# GeoTransform Values not available

Tags: image-processing, gdal, rgdal

I am using R on a Windows 7, Intel i5 machine with 4GB RAM, 1TB Storage and Radeon Graphic Card. I tried to import a .bsq file with name ocif of around 110MB using the rgdal package which was installed successfully.

Here is my code:

```
map = readGDAL("ocif.bsq")
```

Which yielded:

> ocif.bsq has GDAL driver ENVI and has 1145 rows ans 3940 columns
>   Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.19Gb

In addition the warning message:

> In readGDAL("ocif.bsq") : GeoTransform Values not available.

Can someone please let me understand this? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the memory limit R gives you. If your R build is for 32 bit you will have a thetotrical 2gb space but usually it is less which could be the case for you.if this is the problem try install r64 bit version

Comment: Thank you. It worked with 64 bit.